# How to visualize PanelGrid components inside DataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, pagination

I am trying to create a DataTable (because of pagination) with PanelGrid like this.

[image]

My code for the grid is taken from [PrimeFaces website](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf):

```
<p:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="7">1995-96 NBA Playoffs</p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="2">Conf. Semifinals</p:column>
                <p:column colspan="2">Conf. Finals</p:column>
                <p:column colspan="2">NBA Finals</p:column>
                <p:column>Champion</p:column>
            </p:row>
        </f:facet>
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">Seattle</p:column>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">4</p:column>

            <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">Seattle</p:column>
            <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">4</p:column>

            <p:column rowspan="5">Seattle</p:column>
            <p:column rowspan="5">2</p:column>

            <p:column rowspan="11" style="font-weight: bold;">Chicago</p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>Houston</p:column>
            <p:column>0</p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
```

When i put the code for the grid between DataTable tags, it just show the header and pagination line. Some idea how to make such PanelGrids with pagination?

Comment: I imagine to have data structure like this on the picture inside DataTable where each row is combination of the rows from PanelGrid. Is it possible and how to do this if it is?

Comment: You can use `p:subTable`. See [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `p:panelGrid` for that. You can use `p:dataTable` and `p:row` with `p:column rowspan="2"` and `p:column colspan="2"` like you have in your code. In case if table is more complicated use `p:subTable`. Example of subtable is [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf).